# Not able to load file from external csv file in d3plus-react.

Tags: reactjs, d3plus

Please find the following code:

```
class Timedown extends Component {
  state = {
    data: d3.csv("./data/d3plus.csv", function(error, dataset) {
      if (error) return console.error(error);
    })
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I think so you are not returning data after reading the csv file.

```
    d3.csv('./data/d3plus.csv', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return;
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App width={960} height={640} data={data} />,
            document.getElementById('root'),
        )
    });

function App({width, height, data}) {
    const config = { data, x: "year", y: "value", text: "name" }; 
    return (
       // you can manipulate the data here using data
      // your html goes here
       <LinePlot config={{ config }} />

    )
}
```

Comment: I have index.js where I've render the root dom element and code is working when I mentioned data as you can see from the image in the code

Comment: Then the issue is data is not binding with LinePlot itseems. Try directly using this <LinePlot config={ data } />

Comment: Check out this render method,                                                        
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const config = {
      data,
      x: "year",
      y: "value",
      text: "name"
    };
    return <LinePlot config={{ config }} />;
  }
}

Comment: Don't use double braces {{ }} use single braces <LinePlot config={ config } />

Comment: I tried with {} but still not working. Config is an object, therefore, it should be mention in {{}}, I think

Comment: I have used Recharts for LineChart for one of my project. You can try that

Comment: It's not about the chart, there is something wrong with data import. Thanks for suggestion though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156587/discussion-between-sandeep-and-ajaykumar).